# ElephantBird UDF: ORDER BY on a json field generates a syntax error

Tags: apache-pig, elephantbird

I am using Pig 0.13.0 on Hadoop 1.2.1. To process JSON files, I am also using ElephantBird UDF version of 4.5. Until now I didn't have a big problem with the UDF but when I tried to order an alias by a json field, pig compiler isn't very happy, I got the following error:

```
Failed to parse: <file find.pig, line 13, column 35>  Syntax error, unexpected symbol at or near 'long'
```

The script looks like this (look at the ORDER statement):

```
...
records = LOAD '$INPUT' USING com.twitter.elephantbird.pig.load.JsonLoader('-nestedLoad') AS (json:map[]);
sorted_records = ORDER records BY (long)json#'imp' desc;
...
```

I tried removing (long) but to no avail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot order your records by a value in the map returned by the `JsonLoader` or do a type conversion in an `order by`. What you can do is project the value of `json#'imp'` to a field in your record an then order by:

```
records = FOREACH records GENERATE json, (long)json#'imp' AS imp:long;
sortedrecords = ORDER records BY imp desc;
```